# Create new user in Glassfish server with a Servlet

Tags: java, authentication, servlets, glassfish

I'm using form bases authentication for a web service that needs to be deployed soon. I have been creating users into Glassfish server manually but i need to make a JSP where an user can register by himself. ¿How can I do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after looking on several places it seems it's not possible and I should be using JDBC Realms.